# How to compare a date is in current month or not using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Sorry, for my question. Actually i am not able to clarify my question for my hurry up.
I have a table like below :

[image]

This table is LoginHistoryTable(When a user login my application, his history insert this table according to UserId). I get all data from table as a list.

Now i want to Know : How many times they logged in this month and the last month.

Comment: Here a million dollar question: Did you try _anything_?

Answer (score 13):

This is really simple but here you go. You need to compare month and year.

```
boo isCurrentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month == otherDate.Month 
    && DateTime.Now.Year == otherDate.Year;
```

Answer (score -3):

Something like..

```
public bool IsThisMonth(DateTime dt)
{
    return dt.Month == DateTime.Now.Month;
}
```

Comment: You need to compare year.